# How to auto increment the keys in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have a multithreading app. Multiple threads are putting things into a Map in which each thing must have a unique ID. Right now I'm using a TreeMap for this purpose like this:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Thing> things = new TreeMap<>();
things.put(things.isEmpty() ? 0 : things.lastKey() + 1, thing);
```

But a TreeMap is not thread-safe, so I decided to replace it with a ConcurrentHashMap.

But how could I achieve the same using a HashMap? So how to generate a new unique key for each thing I put into it?

Comment: Why not use a concurrent tree map? Raw hash maps aren't inherently thread safe either.

Comment: It looks to me like your last key will always be equal to size which means you can use any other thread safe Map implementation. Also why not a thread safe List as you seem so just build an ordered sequence.

Comment: do you have to be using `Thing` here? cause if you want just separate ID's (integer, long, UUID, etc ) there are simpler ways

Comment: @MadPhysicist I could make my TreeMap concurrent using Collections.synchronizedMap() (@Oleg and any other collection) but I heard this can lead to a much worse performance than using a ConcurrentHashMap. (whole collection gets blocked vs. only the item accessed)

Comment: @A4L I didn't mention but items might also get removed, not only added.

Comment: @Eugene Thing objects I have to store in some collection that is thread-safe and every object in it should have a unique integer key.

Comment: I think u meant unique value

Comment: @tom, OK then stick with the map, and if the keys do not have to be a sequence then use uuid as shown in Oscar's answer.

Comment: Did you consider to use a concurrent list, e.g. _CopyOnWriteArrayList_? The list creates an integer key implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate unique Integers using Javas AtomicInteger class. It has a thread-safe getAndIncrement() method for that purpose.

However, this may cause some unpredictable bug in HashMap even with different keys. Some example listed here: [Is a HashMap thread-safe for different keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688629/is-a-hashmap-thread-safe-for-different-keys)

So be sure to use a thread-safe map, or some other faster thread-safe datastructure like a Vector. If you know an upper bound of how many elements will be added, using an array with the index from AtomicInteger would be fastest, as you can avoid all synchronization.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Combined with `ConcurrentHashMap` why not?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) for the keys, it's [extremely unlikely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24876263/201359) that a collision will occur. Something like this:

```
// import java.util.UUID;
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();
```

Comment: Without knowing OP's specific use case, can you really say that it's worth the effort?

Comment: Seems to fit the bill of "a new unique key for each thing". And is not too much of an effort ;)

Comment: Thank you, but I only need auto increment integers, not more.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can write (something) like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(-1);

map.compute(x, (l, r) -> {
    return ai.incrementAndGet();
})
```

`compute` is documented to be atomic