# Java arbitrary comparator on Object

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

Let's say I am building a `TreeSet` of an object for which the ordering depends on only one value.

I cannot do

```
TreeSet<Foo> tree = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Foo::getX));
```

because if I add two different `Foo` objects with the same `x` then one would replace the other (i.e. if I do `tree.add(foo1)` and `tree.add(foo2)`, `tree.size()` will be `1` instead of `2`).

I could compare every field of `Foo`, but I would like two instances of `Foo` to be considered distinct, even if every field is the same.

One solution that "almost works" would be

```
TreeSet<Foo> tree = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Foo::getX).thenComparing(Foo::hashCode));
```

But this would fail when there is a hash collision.

**In summary**, I am looking to something similar to

```
TreeSet<Foo> tree = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Foo::getX).thenComparing(Foo::getInternalAddress));
```

But of course we don't have access to such method.

#### Workarounds

I know there are workarounds:

- if I don't care about the objects themselves but just how many are in the tree, I can use a multiset `TreeMap<Foo, Integer>` (and comparing all the fields) that give me how many `Foo`s for a specific `x`
- if I do care about the objects (I am making reference equality checks) I can use a different multiset `TreeMap<Foo, List<Foo>>` (or `TreeMap<Integer, List<Foo>>` with the key being `x`). But if there are very few "duplicated" foos, this is a waste of space taken by all the singleton lists.

So while I know there are workarounds with a `TreeMap`, I still wonder if there is a way to do that with just a `TreeSet`.

Comment: Can you make changes to `Foo`? How about simply adding a `UUID` field and sort by that?

Comment: I also slightly suspect that this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Sounds like you want a sorted list, not a set. See [Why is there no SortedList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8725387/12299000)

Comment: @Sweeper I could do that. If there is a way without modifying Foo, I'd rather have it, but this is a good workaround. Is there any risk of collision with `UUID.randomUUID()`? But I guess if I worry about collision I could simply have a static counter of the instances instead.

Comment: @kaya3 I do want `O(log n)` insertion and deletion tough.

Comment: @Ricola A sensible implementation of a sorted list (or bag) will have O(log n) insertion and removal. See the linked Q&A for some suggestions. Depending on how you intend to use your collection, a priority queue may be a better option anyway.

Comment: @Ricola How do you want to order multiple `Foo` instances, when they have the same `X` value? How do you define your ordering of multiple `Foo` instances in that case? Why is one `Foo` instance placed "before" another `Foo` instance based on your desired comparator?

Comment: @Gardener and @Progman I don't care about the ordering of two foos with the same X. What I need though is the comparator to be consistent with `Object::equals` and consistent with itself (i.e `a.compare(b)` returns always the same with same `a` and `b` and  `b.compare(a)` to be consistent with `a.compare(b)`). This is why I gave the example of the internal address as I don't know how else I could have it (other than the UUI solution suggested by @Sweeper). What I am looking for is a BST where the nodes are ordered based on `x`, and ties are broken arbitrarily.

Comment: @kaya3 "A sensible implementation of a sorted list (or bag) will have O(log n) insertion and removal." => which is the multiset implementation I mentioned in my question

Comment: But the "multiset implementation" in your question is a set, not a bag. Rather than trying to make a set behave the way you want, it would be simpler to use a data structure which is supposed to behave that way.

Comment: You could try using `System.identityHashCode` instead of `Foo.hashCode` for the second comparison. There are still no guarantees about hash collisions though.

Comment: @Sweeper "I also slightly suspect that this is an XY problem". I am not trying to solve a problem in particular, but a similar set of problems and I was curious if other solutions exist. To give more details, in competitive programming, I often need to have sorted objects based on some fields with fast insertion and retrieval. The multiset implementation is a bit cumbersome so I wanted to know if there is a way to achieve that with only a set (so it's faster to code). Your solution does meet the criteria, or I keep a generic multiset implementation somewhere that I can quickly paste.

Comment: @kaya3 "But the "multiset implementation" in your question is a set, not a bag." Not sure what you mean here, `TreeMap<Foo, List<Foo>>` is the implementation of a bag.

Comment: Have a look at Guava’s [`Ordering.arbitrary`](https://guava.dev/releases/31.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#arbitrary())

Comment: @StuartMarks did we consider adding this to the JDK? If not, why?

Comment: It's on the radar but it's not particularly high priority.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guava provides [`Ordering.arbitrary()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#arbitrary()) which you can use to construct your desired `Comparator`:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(Foo::getX).thenComparing(Ordering.arbitrary())
```

`Ordering.arbitrary()` internally uses `System.identityHashCode` which *almost* solves your "order arbitrary, but consider identity" problem, except there's no guarantee that `identityHashCode` will never collide (trivially, since it's a 32bit value and a Java project can easily create more than 2<sup>32</sup> objects, given enough memory).

`Ordering.arbitrary()` uses some neat tricks to still sort objects with colliding `identityHashCode` values in a consistent (but arbitrary!) way, see [its code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v31.1/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.java#L325).

Comment: Isn't it more something like `.thenComparing(Ordering.arbitrary());`?

Comment: @Ricola: yes, absolutely, that was a typo, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

## With an external library

See [@Joachim Sauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73932853/7424948) and @Stuart Marks's comment : Guava's [`Ordering.arbitrary()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#arbitrary()).

## Without external libraries

Add an id field to `Foo` that is unique for each instance.

#### With UUID class

*Suggested by @Sweeper in a comment.*

```
class Foo {
  private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
...
}
...
new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Foo::getX).thenComparing(Foo::getUUID));
```

The chance of collisions are almost inexistent (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24876263/7424948), but if you are paranoid you can use the custom instance counter below.

#### Instance counter

```
class Foo {
  // if only one thread, otherwise use AtomicInteger for thread-safe.
  // assuming we'll get less than Integer.MAX_VALUE instances, otherwise use long.
  private static int counter = 0;
  private int id;

  public Foo(...){
    id = counter++;
  } 
...
}
...
new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Foo::getX).thenComparingInt(Foo::getId));
```

Advantage over `UUID` is that it takes less space (32 bits per instance instead of 128 bits) and that there is less computation to get the id.

Comment: The `int` field can potentially suffer the exact same problem that `identityHashCode` has when it overflows. `long` would be safer here, but even that isn't guaranteed safe (since more than 2^64 `Foo`  objects could be created in the lifetime of a VM).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I agree, but this is why I wrote a comment over the field. It depends on the use case, the assumptions and the constraints. In the really worst case this can be a BigInteger.

Comment: "since more than 2^64 Foo objects could be created in the lifetime of a VM". Not really. If you want to do that in 10 years, you have to allocate 58,454,204,609 Objects/second.

Comment: Also, I think a long has pretty much the same constraints as `Ordering.arbitrary()` current implementation (2^32 different hashcodes and then 2^32 different AtomicIntegers for collisions)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: fair point! And yes, @Ricola, a `long` would end up being roughly equivalent to what `Ordering.arbitrary()` does.